# Q : In QT C++, How to save selected row in file from TableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

This is the code for save all data from table in test.txt file.
    I want all selected data by checkbox in test.txt file. I tried here to add all table data into .txt file.
{

```
  // Table Widget 
m_pTableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
m_pTableWidget->setRowCount(3);
m_pTableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
m_TableHeader<<"A"<<"B"<<"C";
m_pTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(m_TableHeader);
     // Insert Data into Table
m_pTableWidget->setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("JFX1234567"));
m_pTableWidget->setItem(1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("JFY1234567"));
      // Add checkBox
QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem("1");
item1->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
m_pTableWidget->setItem(0, 0, item1);
QTableWidgetItem *item2 = new QTableWidgetItem("2");
item2->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
m_pTableWidget->setItem(1, 0, item2);

//  Load data in Qstring
QString textData;
int rows = m_pTableWidget->rowCount();
int columns = m_pTableWidget->columnCount();

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        textData += m_pTableWidget->data(m_pTableWidget->setItem(i,j)).toString();
    }
}
QFile txtFile("test.txt");    
if(txtFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate)) {

QTextStream out(&txtFile);
out << textData;

txtFile.close();

QFile txtFile("test.txt");    

if(txtFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
{
QTextStream out(&txtFile);
out << textData;
txtFile.close();
}
```

But, I don't know why I can't save data in Qstring.I got many errors.

Comment: Qt5 and Qt4. You've tagged your question with both, which one are you using?

Comment: `m_pTableWidget->data(m_pTableWidget->setItem(i,j))` what is this line doing? `setItem` takes three arguments and returns `void`. Did you mean to use [`item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#item)?

Comment: With that aside: "_I got many errors._" show us what errors you're getting, the most prominent ones at least.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I am using Qt 5.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (m_pTableWidget->item(i,j)->checkState() == Qt::Checked){
    textData += m_pTableWidget->item(i,j)->text();
}
```

[QTableWidgetItem *QTableWidget::item(int row, int column) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#item)
[QString QTableWidgetItem::text() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#text)

Comment: This is will save my all the data of table widget, But i want only selected data from checkbox in .txt file. any guidance please.Thanks in advance. 
and sorry for late reply, i was little busy due to festivals.

Comment: Thanks it is working but this will give only 1 and 2 number. I want all the selected rows. so should i add this line in table widget ? `m_pTableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows); `